# Which game is this token showing rocks in the sea from?

Tags: identify-this-game-piece

Can anyone help identify the game this token comes from? I was moving some boxes and found it lying on a shelf. It's blue and purple and appears to be showing rocks in the sea.

[image: the piece in question]

Comment: Do you own Spirit Island? There are irregular water tiles like that, depending on edition they might have rocks on it

Comment: @Zibelas not spirit island, no version I've ever seen looks like that, and the edges are wrong for that game

Comment: As someone who plays far too much Spirit Island, can confirm that it that is not a piece

Comment: I do own spirit island, and will check the box for that game, but others here seem to doubt that answer. Thanks.